# Transferring the commit messages from branch to master

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-merge

We have currently been working on a separate git branch which has now been merged into the master and the development branch is to be deleted but Im afraid the commit messages for the development branch will also be deleted.

Is there a way of transferring the messages to the master branch?

Comment: If you're not doing doing a squash merge, the commits themselves aren't lost, and neither are the messages.

Comment: @bejado Even after deleting the branch??  Im a bit hesitant there

Comment: Deleting a branch doesn't delete the commits themselves, it only deletes a "pointer" to a specific commit. As long as all of your development branch commits are accessible via a branch (which they are- master now contains them) git will not garbage collect them.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a branch will not delete the commits made in the branch. They will still show up in the repo network/history.[Example in GitLab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8HsQ.png)